# Transit Visa of Abu dhabi to travel Dubai

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, dubai, uae, abu-dhabi

I am Indian passport holder and If I get a 48 hours UAE transit visa from Etihad, for Abu dhabi airport. Can I go to Dubai Emirates for sight seeing and return back to Abu dhabi airport for travel to next destination?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you can.  Dubai and Abu Dhabi are in the same country, namely the United Arab Emirates (UAE), and if you have a visa for the UAE, you can travel anywhere in the country.

Comment: It's also a 150 km distance, so don't try to do this between flights a few hours apart.

Comment: Is it ok, if transit time is 12 hours excluding 3 hours check in time?